# Favicon dissapears on reload after following internal link

Tags: html, firefox, favicon

I've a local site, and when I follow some internal link:

```
page.html#heading1
```

and reload the page -- the favicon is gone. It is there if I reload back to

```
page.html
```

I guess I'm missing something trivial.

The icon is linked as:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="_static/icon.png"/>
```

**Edit**:

Now, that I've tried it in Chromium -- I think it's a Firefox issue.

**Edit 2**:

```
function setFavicon() {
  var link = "_static/icon.png"
  $('<link href="'+ link +'" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />').appendTo('head');
}
setFavicon()
```

Doesn't work for me (I use jquery 1.9).

**Edit 3**:

None of the following works:

```
$('link[type*=icon]').detach().appendTo('head');

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('link[type*=icon]').detach().appendTo('head');
});

$(document).ready( function() {
    var link = "_static/icon.png"
    $('<link href="'+ link +'" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />').appendTo('head');
});
```

**Edit 4**:

Found an effect: if I go up, and then go back -- the page is still `page.html#heading1` but the favicon is showed. When I reload the page the favicon goes away again.

Comment: Which is your browser?

Comment: maybe its a cache issue? the icon path may be broken and it works only when using cache? try `ctrl+F5`

Comment: @Elisha: nope -- I tried it.

Answer (score 2):

See [disappearing favicon in FF](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/javascript/the-case-of-the-disappearing-favicon/)